# MvvmCross 4.1 - MvxImageViewLoader not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I started a new Xamarin.iOS project but I can't get the MvxImageViewLoader working. I've added the latest DownloadCache, File and Json plugins (version 4.1) and configured them inside my Setup file:

```cs
protected override void AddPluginsLoaders (MvxLoaderPluginRegistry registry)
{
    registry.AddConventionalPlugin<MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache.iOS.Plugin>();
    registry.AddConventionalPlugin<MvvmCross.Plugins.File.iOS.Plugin>();

    base.AddPluginsLoaders (registry);
}

protected override void InitializeLastChance ()
{   
    MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache.PluginLoader.Instance.EnsureLoaded();
    MvvmCross.Plugins.File.PluginLoader.Instance.EnsureLoaded();
    MvvmCross.Plugins.Json.PluginLoader.Instance.EnsureLoaded();

    base.InitializeLastChance ();
}
```

Inside a custom MvxTableViewCell I'm trying to bind an image:

```cs
public partial class MyTableViewCell : MvxTableViewCell
{
    public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString ("MyTableViewCell");
    public static readonly UINib Nib;

    private readonly MvxImageViewLoader _imageViewLoader;

    static MyTableViewCell ()
    {
        Nib = UINib.FromName ("MyTableViewCell", NSBundle.MainBundle);
    }

    public MyTableViewCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
        _imageViewLoader = new MvxImageViewLoader(() => imgLarge);

        this.DelayBind (() => {
            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MyTableViewCell, MyViewModel>();                
            set.Bind (_imageViewLoader).To (vm => vm.ImageUrlLarge);
            set.Apply();
        }); 
    }
}
```

The relevant error in the Application Output:

```cs
mvx: Diagnostic: 366.64 failed to download image http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-2-9DK3D-bo8/T-g6U58ZU_I/AAAAAAAADpQ/NKEmG72Hl0I/s1600/Funny_Hamster_04.jpg : TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'MvxImageCache`1' from assembly ‘…/MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache.dll'.
.....
at MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache.MvxDynamicImageHelper`1+<RequestImageAsync>d__29[T].MoveNext () [0x001a7] in C:\vcs\git\MvvmCross-Plugins\DownloadCache\MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache\MvxDynamicImageHelper.cs:135
```

Looking at the error and the source code for that line, it seems the DownloadCache plugin isn't able to resolve the ImageCache:

```cs
var cache = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxImageCache<T>>();
```

Did I not register something that I was supposed to? Is this a bug with the latest version perhaps? All the tutorials, questions, etc I see online are for version  3.X. Has anyone gotten the DownloadCache plugin working with 4.X?

**UPDATE**
I created a new MvvmCross solution to showcase this problem. You can reproduce the problem here:
https://github.com/ogoldfinger/MvvmCrossDownloadCacheTest

Comment: What does the exception tell you when doing Mvx.Resolve?

Comment: Could not load type 'MvxImageCache`1' from assembly '...MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache.dll'

Comment: There must be more, something like an inner exception or something else.

Comment: Would it be helpful if I pasted the entire application output? The only part I left out from the above stack trace are related to this: `MvvmCross.Platform.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.InternalTryResolve`

Comment: Have you referenced the package that is ment for IOS and not for the core project, if there is one? Do you have a MvxLoaderPluginBootstrapAction for MvxImageCache? I'm just guessing here, but I think those two can be easy to miss

Comment: I don't see an iOS version of the plugin. I have bootstraps for the Download, File and Json plugins. Do I need one for ImageCache? The Download plugin is supposed to register it: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Plugins/blob/93a82fce924b0a058e3fd55bbf2b4e3aaf3e061e/DownloadCache/MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache.iOS/Plugin.cs#L35

Comment: I created a new project from the starter kit so you can reproduce the problem. I believe this solution should show the image properly but the same error is shown instead. https://github.com/ogoldfinger/MvvmCrossDownloadCacheTest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manually install this Nuget: [System.Collections.Immutable](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections.Immutable)

This is an issue of DownloadCache plugin, missing dependency on System.Collections.Immutable. See this: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Plugins/issues/78

The issue is fixed already, so we won't need to do this in the next update of DownloadCache package.

Comment: When trying this now (even updating the the downloadcache plugin to 4.1.1 I get the following error "Could not install package 'System.Resources.ResourceManager 4.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.". Am I missing something here?